# How to propagate variables in a stream in java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

I would be currious to know how to propagate variable into a stream in java 8.
An example is better than a long explaination, so how would you convert the following (abstract) code into streams:

```
Map<Integer,A> myMap = new HashMap();


for (Entry<Integer,A> entry : myMap)
{
    int param1=entry.getValue().getParam1();
    List param2=entry.getValue().getParam2();
    for (B b : param2)
    {
        System.out.println(""+entry.getKey()+"-"+param1+"-"+b.toString());
    }
}
```

Knowing that this example is a simplification of the problem (for example, i need "param1" more than once in the next for loop)

So far, the only idea i have is to store all the informations i need into a tuple to finally use the forEach stream method over this tuple.
(Not sure to be very clear....)

Edit:I simplified my example too much. My case is more something like that:

```
Map<Integer,A> myMap = new HashMap();


for (Entry<Integer,A> entry : myMap)
{
    int param1=entry.getValue().getParam1();
    CustomList param2=entry.getValue().getParam2();
    for (int i = 0; i<param2.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(""+entry.getKey()+"-"+param1+"-"+param2.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

I could write something like that with stream:

```
myMap.entrySet().stream()
    .forEach(
        e -> IntStream.range(0, e.getValue.getParam2().getSize())
             .forEach(
                i -> System.out.println(e.getKey()+"-"+e.getValue().getParam1()+"-"+e.getValue.getParam2.get(i))
             )
    );
```

However, what i have instead of "e.getValue.getParam2()" in my real case is much more complex (a sequence of 5-6 methods) and heavier than just retrieving a variable (it executes some logic), so i would like to avoid to repeat e.getValue.getParam2 (once in just before the forEach, and once in the forEach)

i know that it's maybe not the best use case for using stream, but I am learning about it and would like to know about the limits

Thanks!

Comment: There might not be any advantage in trying to change this into streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
myMap.forEach(
    (key, value) -> value.getParam2().forEach(
        b -> System.out.println(key+"-"+value.getParam1()+"-"+b)
    )
);
```

That is, for each key/value pair, iterate through `value.getParam2()`. For each one of those, print out string formatted as you specified. I'm not sure what that gets you, other than being basically what you had before, but using streams.

*Update*

Responding to updates to your question, this:

```
myMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
    final CustomList param2 = value.getParam2();
    IntStream.range(0, param2.getSize()).forEach(
        i -> System.out.println(key+"-"+value.getParam1()+"-"+param2.get(i))
    )
});
```

Here we assign the result of `getParam2()` to a final variable, so it is only calculated once. Final (and [effectively final](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#accessing-members-of-an-enclosing-class)) variables are visible inside lambda functions.

(Thank you to Holger for the suggestions.)

Comment: Thanks! I simplified too much my case, I updated my post, and now I think I explained the situation better

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's exactly what i wanted to know ^^

Comment: In your second code snippet, you are still calling `e.getValue().getParam2()` twice. By the way, if all you’re going to do with a `Collection`’s stream is `forEach`, you don’t need a stream at all, i.e. instead of `myMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> …` you can simply use `myMap.entrySet().forEach(e -> …`, but in case of maps, you can even simplify it further: myMap.forEach( (key,value) -> …` removes the burden of having to deal with `Map.Entry`, invoking `getKey()` and `getValue()`, altogether…

Comment: @Holger Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are more features in the Java 8 API than just streams. Especially, if you just want to process all elements of a collection, you don’t need streams.

You can simplify every form of `coll.stream().forEach(consumer)` to `coll.forEach(consumer)`. This applies to `map.entrySet()` as well, however, if you want to process all mappings of a `Map`, you can use [`forEach` on the `Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) directly, providing a `BiConsumer<KeyType,ValueType>` rather than a `Consumer<Map.Entry<KeyType,ValueType>>`, which can greatly improve the readability:

```
myMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
    int        param1 = value.getParam1();
    CustomList param2 = value.getParam2();
    IntStream.range(0, param2.size()).mapToObj(param2::get)
        .forEach(obj -> System.out.println(key+"-"+param1+"-"+obj));
});
```

It’s worth thinking about adding a `forEach(Consumer<ElementType>)` method to your `CustomList`, even if the `CustomList` doesn’t support the other standard collection operations…

Comment: Thanks!
It was just a simple example, that was maybe too simple. What i really wanted to know was how to store a "complex" calculation in the stream to reuse it many times later. (param2 does not have to be a custom list, it could be someting like param2=value.getA().getB().calc(value.getParam1()).getC etc...
Something that you don't want to repeat everywhere in the stream
However, i did not know about the map.forEach, thanks!